# Trouble getting values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a foreach() method where a message for an email is concocted:

```
foreach($this->fields as $key => $field)
            $msg .= "$key :  $field \n";
```

My problem is that I need to create a mysql_query() to insert the field values into my database and I don't know how I can retrieve that data to actually insert into the database.

How can I get it?

Let me know what other code I need to provide if you need any more.

Comment: What do you mean, retrieve the data? You're retrieving it right there in your foreach loop.

Comment: The data is being put into the $msg variable though. I need it to go into separate keys.

Comment: Define data. Do you mean what's inside `$key` and `$field`? If so, then you know how to access it now.

Comment: I define data as what is inside $field. I need to create a separate $key variable, and set that $key variable to the $field value

Comment: I guess your `fields`-variable is an associative array containing the MySQL-Row name (which would be `$key`) and the corresponding value (`$field'')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a dynamically named variable inside a foreach loop. What you can do, though, is create an array of keys with $field as the value:

```
$keys = array(); $i = 0;
foreach($this->fields as $key => $field){ 
   $keys[$i] = $field; $i++;
}
```

However, this is kind of roundabout, because you can just get the same behavior by getting it like this:

```
$this->fields[$key] // will return $field
```

I hope I understood your question correctly through your comments.